# Update Version for Multi-line text field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, version-history, multiple-lines-of-text

I have a SharePoint list with a multi-line text field.  I have the option to "append changes to existing text" turned on.  This option will show the version history for each change.

Is there a way to use the SharePoint API to change this version history (eg change the name on the version history)?

I can retrieve the version history, I am just not sure how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the SharePoint list item with new name & create a new version of the list item.

It will not update the information in existing version of list item.